# How to wait for openRead function to complete on one file before moving on to the next?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to load multiple files, in a certain order, inside of Dart. The files are of a modified GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification) type and are such interconnected through 'ids' between the files. Because of this I'm trying to load each file one by one but due to their large size I am using the openRead method of the File class to stream them in line-by-line using the LineSplitter transformer.

How they are being loaded in (start is the byte offset of the openRead method)

```dart
Stream<List<int>> getFileStream(String fileName, {int start}) => File(fileName).openRead(start);

// Example Stream

Stream<List<int>> stops = getFileStream("stops.txt", start: 117);
Stream<List<int>> routes = getFileStream("routes.txt", start: 131);

// How the stream data is being read
stops
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(LineSplitter())
    .listen(
      (String line) {
        List<String> values = line.split(',');

        // Do stuff..
      },
      onDone: () { },
      onError: (e) { print(e.toString()); }
    );

routes
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(LineSplitter())
    .listen(
      (String line) {
        List<String> values = line.split(',');

        // Do stuff..
        // Error occurs here as well since the processing taking place here depends on the processing which takes place when the stops file is read
      },
      onDone: () { },
      onError: (e) { print(e.toString()); }
    );
```

However since I'm loading in multiple files within the same function and they are all streams with a listen callback set and they depend on the processing of the files that came before them to be COMPLETELY finished the program is producing errors since all the files are being read at once line by line and the processing of the other files has not finished.

Ideally, I would like to use an `await for (String line in stops)` line or something similar, however that produces the following error which I do not know how to solve:

`The type 'Stream<List<int>>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Stream with a type argument that can be assigned to 'String'.`

This error still shows up even if I do the `.transform` calls on the stream before the `await for` line.

I've also tried chaining together the `onDone` methods of the streams which produced an abomination of code which still didn't work (Lists that were created and added to within the function were empty upon returning???)

It would be nice to use the `await for` syntax as that produces cleaner code, however I do not want to pollute the whole function tree with async, await functions especially the `main()` function.

The only thing that worked was using the Completer class from `dart:async` however the `onDone` methods needed to be chained for this and the code was barely readable.

Any help as well as some guidance on Futures and async/await would be appreciated.

Comment: The return type of the function is `List<List<dynamic>>` as it is a list of lists of GTFS Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```dart
await for (var line in stops
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(LineSplitter())) {


    List<String> values = line.split(',');
    // Do stuff..
    // Error occurs here as well since the processing taking place here depends on the processing which takes place when the stops file is read
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Do you have any idea why calling `stops.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter())` and then `await for (var line in stops)` on separate lines does not work? Does transform() modify the original stream or return a new one?

Comment: Consuming a Stream...consumes the Stream. If you want to consume the data twice you need to cache it.